# Not Found 404 Error Django Crud Application

Tags: django

i am creating a Django Crud Application.i am beginner of django.i have it crudapplication while i testing through postman i ran into the problem with i attached below. and what i tried so far i attached below.all the source codes.

`Not Found: / [29/Apr/2023 10:40:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2272 Not Found: / [29/Apr/2023 10:40:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2272 Not Found: /favicon.ico [29/Apr/2023 10:40:07] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2323 Not Found: /users [29/Apr/2023 10:40:11] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 404 2305`

**urls.py**

```
 from django.contrib import admin from django.urls
 import path from django.conf.urls 
import url from Student import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
    
         url(r'^user$',views.userApi),
        url(r'^user$',views.userApi),
        url(r'^user/([0-9]+)$',views.userApi),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    ]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
address = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
fee = models.IntegerField()
```

**serilize.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from Student.models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Student
fields = '__all__'
read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from Student.serilize import StudentSerializer
from Student.models import Student

@csrf_exempt
def userApi(request,id=0):
if request.method=='GET':
user = Student.objects.all()
user_serializer=StudentSerializer(user,many=True)
return JsonResponse(user_serializer.data,safe=False)
elif request.method=='POST':
user_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
user_serializer=StudentSerializer(data=user_data)
if user_serializer.is_valid():
user_serializer.save()
return JsonResponse("Added Successfully",safe=False)
return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)
elif request.method=='PUT':
user_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
user=Student.objects.get(id=id)
user_serializer=StudentSerializer(user,data=user_data)
if user_serializer.is_valid():
user_serializer.save()
return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully",safe=False)
return JsonResponse("Failed to Update")
elif request.method=='DELETE':
user=Student.objects.get(id=id)
user.delete()
return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully",safe=False)
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class StudentConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField
name = 'Student'
```